# Проблема с преобразованием string в int php

Tags: php, числа

Есть скрипт:

```
$passport = '28 48 399999';
$passport = str_replace(' ','', $passport);
$passport = intval($passport);
var_dump($passport);
```

Его dump: `int(2147483647)`

Вопрос: почему? пробелы убрал, а в число преобразует кое-как...

Comment: 2147483647 это максимальное значение int. У вас просто не влазит в int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 147 483 647 — это 2<sup>31</sup>–1, максимальное целое число, помещающееся в 32 бита. Ваше число 2 848 399 999 больше, поэтому PHP решил преобразовать его к самому близкому значению, которое может быть представлено.

Похапэ искаропки не умеет в длинные целые. Должны быть математические пакеты, если вам это действительно нужно.

Comment: на 64-битных системах максималка может быть 9223372036854775807. Может ТС посоветовать перейти?) шутка за 300